# I have a .glb with the skeleton, all of its animations, and meshes. How can I add the particles folder to the animations happening?

Tags: animation, particles

To expand a bit more on this topic, I have a .glb file, in which there is basically a skinned mesh, with all the poses, animations, armatures, and actual meshes + vertex groups.

However, when I am playing an animation, while animation does happen but all the particles are missing. I do have a particles folder with full of .dds files, but I am not sure if it is possible to include them.

I am trying to do all this with a League of Legends character, to be more specific.

Anyone knows if its possible to include all those particles?